# How do I use environment variables in a SvelteKit app hosted on Cloudflare Pages?

Tags: environment-variables, svelte, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages

I am making a site for a very small organisation I am involved in, and have been asked to design it in a way where hosting costs virtually nothing. I have opted to use SvelteKit (hosted on Cloudflare Pages) and PocketBase (hosted on PocketHost). Using hardcoded secrets, I was able to achieve the desired behavior (a news, team and projects page), however I want to switch to a safer/more robust solution, using environment variables.

I want to be able to access the environment variables inside `+page.server.js` files, to log into my PocketBase instance. I also want to be able to test with Wrangler, which I have had trouble with (for example: what is my `entry-point` supposed to be?). I have read the docs of both Cloudflare pages and SvelteKit in regards to env variables, SvelteKit and Cloudflare, but it doesn't really make sense to me.

I am a very new developer and I'm sorry if something went right over my head, or it's super obvious, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the CloudFlare UI, go to Pages » your project » Settings » Environment variables. Define all your environment variables here.

In your SvelteKit app, access them via `'$env/static/private'` if they can be baked in at build time or `'$env/dynamic/private'` if they need to be read at runtime. For example:

```js
import { API_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
```

And that’s it. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-private.

Comment: How would I test them locally?

Comment: You can define them locally via a `.env` file. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables

Comment: so you will need to maintain 2 copies on env vars one in cloudflare dashboard and one in .env file ?

Comment: Yes, though you can probably keep them in sync via something like Wrangler.

Comment: Should the private variables be encrypted? Or would encrypting the variables interfere with Sveltekit somehow?

Comment: It’s up to you if you want to encrypt your environment variables. They’re only used by your code, not by SvelteKit, so it won’t interfere with SvelteKit. You would need to decrypt them before using them at the point of your code where you’re accessing them.