Environment Variables not populated
I'm trying to get environment variables working in a Sveltekit web application hosted in Cloudflare pages.
This issue is specific to Cloudflare Pages. When running locally the environment variables are working correctly using the Sveltekit environment variables notation, eg, '$env/static/public'
The cloudflare build system is set to version 2 (latest).
I've added my environment variables to the dashboard - Workers & Pages > MyWebApp > Settings > Environment Variables.
In terms of environment variable naming I've tried:

having environment variables prefixed with PUBLIC_
having environment variables prefixed with VITE_

In the code I've tried:

import { PUBLIC_VAR } from '$env/static/public' - this results in Error[39m: Module '"$env/static/public"' has no exported member 'PUBLIC_VAR'
import.meta.env.PUBLIC_VAR- having environment variables prefixed with PUBLIC_ - no error during build, but env var is not populated.
process.env.VAR- no error during build, but env var is not populated.
platform.env.VAR  this results in ReferenceError [Error]: platform is not defined.
adding environment variables to the [vars] section in the wrangler.toml file. During the build process I can see these variables displayed, but, when used with '$env/static/public' I still get Error[39m: Module '"$env/static/public"' has no exported member 'PUBLIC_VAR'

I've tried the following commands within the package.json

vite build
npx svelte-kit sync && npx vite build
npx svelte-kit sync && npx svelte-check && vite build

Update
I've discovered that by including a .env file in the source that is built the build succeeds. Unfortunately however I've also discovered the following:

not only are the typescript definitions created, the environment variable values in the .env file are used rather than the corresponding variables set in the cloudflare dashboard.
Only a file named .env or .env.production will work. A file named .env.prod will not.


Have you tried $env//private instead of public? This post shows that putting them in your Cloudfare settings and reading them though $env//private should work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75780218/how-do-i-use-environment-variables-in-a-sveltekit-app-hosted-on-cloudflare-pages

Yes, I've tried both public and private - neither worked.
